# How to check the user is logged in or not in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, authentication, logout

I'm trying to do login page and logout page. I completed the api calling and login successfully, but i am trying to check whether the user is already logged in or not. if the user is logged in and kills the app, and after sometimes the user opens the app means the app should show the home page, but my app shows the sign in page. I tried the below code along with api calling.

```
NSString *mailID=mailTextField.text;
NSString *password=passwordTextField.text;

NSString *noteDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",mailID,password];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"language": @"en"};
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://qa-user.moneyceoapp.com/user/login"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *data = [noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody=data;
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse= (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
        {
            NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"The response is - %@",responseDictionary);
            NSInteger status = [[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue];
            if(status == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defs setObject:mailID forKey:@"email"];
                [defs setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
                [defs synchronize];
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
                 {
                    if(mailID && password)
                    {
                        HomePageVC *homepageVC = [[HomePageVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageVC" bundle:nil];
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:homepageVC animated:YES];
                    }
                 }];
            }
            else
            {
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login FAILURE");
                    [self alertView:@"Invalid user account"];
                }];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

I use class that uses NSUserDefaults to create a dictionary with the parameters of the user's login information. Also, I use Boolean values to check a value equivalently named `joinedApp`.

```
*DataModel.h*

//

@class Message;

// The main data model object
@interface DataModel : NSObject

// The complete history of messages this user has sent and received, in
// chronological order (oldest first).
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* messages;

// Loads the list of messages from a file.
- (void)loadMessages;

// Saves the list of messages to a file.
- (void)saveMessages;

// Adds a message that the user composed himself or that we received through
// a push notification. Returns the index of the new message in the list of
// messages.
- (int)addMessage:(Message*)message;

// Get and set the user's nickname.
- (NSString*)nickname;
- (void)setNickname:(NSString*)name;

// Get and set the secret code that the user is registered for.
- (NSString*)secretCode;
- (void)setSecretCode:(NSString*)string;

// Determines whether the user has successfully joined a chat.
- (BOOL)joinedChat;
- (void)setJoinedChat:(BOOL)value;

- (BOOL)joinedApp;
- (void)setJoinedApp:(BOOL)value;


- (NSString*)userId;
- (NSString*)deviceToken;
- (void)setDeviceToken:(NSString*)token;
@end
```

*DataModel.m*

```
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "Message.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

// We store our settings in the NSUserDefaults dictionary using these keys
static NSString* const NicknameKey = @"Nickname";
static NSString* const SecretCodeKey = @"SecretCode";
static NSString* const JoinedChatKey = @"JoinedChat";
static NSString* const JoinedAppKey = @"JoinedApp";
static NSString* const DeviceTokenKey = @"DeviceToken";
static NSString* const UserId = @"UserId";

@implementation DataModel

+ (void)initialize
{
if (self == [DataModel class])
{
    
    // Register default values for our settings
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:
        @{NicknameKey: @"",
            SecretCodeKey: @"",
            JoinedChatKey: @0,
          JoinedAppKey: @0,
            DeviceTokenKey: @"0",
            UserId:@""}]; 
}
}

// Returns the path to the Messages.plist file in the app's Documents directory
- (NSString*)messagesPath
{
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = paths[0];
return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Messages.plist"];
}

- (void)loadMessages
{
NSString* path = [self messagesPath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    // We store the messages in a plist file inside the app's Documents
    // directory. The Message object conforms to the NSCoding protocol,
    // which means that it can "freeze" itself into a data structure that
    // can be saved into a plist file. So can the NSMutableArray that holds
    // these Message objects. When we load the plist back in, the array and
    // its Messages "unfreeze" and are restored to their old state.

    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    self.messages = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Messages"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
}
else
{
    self.messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
}
}

- (void)saveMessages
{
NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:self.messages forKey:@"Messages"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[data writeToFile:[self messagesPath] atomically:YES];
}

- (int)addMessage:(Message*)message
{
[self.messages addObject:message];
[self saveMessages];
return self.messages.count - 1;
}

- (NSString*)nickname
{
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:NicknameKey];
}

- (void)setNickname:(NSString*)name
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:name forKey:NicknameKey];
 }

- (NSString*)secretCode
{
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:SecretCodeKey];
}

- (void)setSecretCode:(NSString*)string
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:string forKey:SecretCodeKey];
}

- (BOOL)joinedApp
{
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:JoinedAppKey];
}

- (void)setJoinedApp:(BOOL)value
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:value forKey:JoinedAppKey];
}

- (BOOL)joinedChat
{
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:JoinedChatKey];
}

- (void)setJoinedChat:(BOOL)value
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:value forKey:JoinedChatKey];
}

- (NSString*)userId
{
NSString *userId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:UserId];
if (userId == nil || userId.length == 0) {
    userId = [[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userId forKey:UserId];
}
return userId;
}

- (NSString*)deviceToken //used in appdelegate
{
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:DeviceTokenKey];
}

- (void)setDeviceToken:(NSString*)token //used in app delegate
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:DeviceTokenKey];
}


@end
```

I then call the message in the viewIsLoaded method and print verification in the debugger window.

```
*ViewController.h*

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@class DataModel;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) DataModel* dataModel;
@property (retain, strong) UIImage* Image;
@end
```

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "PushChatStarter-Swift.h"

@implementation ViewController
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    _dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
MockApiclient *client = [MockApiclient new];

[client executeRequest];

[self.dataModel setJoinedApp:YES];

if ([_dataModel joinedApp] == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"hi from viewcontroller 1 ");//Here you know which button has pressed

}
...
```

}

 NSUserDefaults:

An interface to the user’s defaults database, where you store key-value pairs persistently across launches of your app.

I also call joinedApp from the login method being used along with other messages.

Comment: sorry I didn't get your answer....I just want to check whether the user is logged in or not...if the user is logged in already the homepage view controller should be displayed even when the app gets killed by the user....